# Asymmetric variant of the Cuthill-McKee algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I need to find a way to modify a matrix (moving only rows and columns, but not single cells) in a kind of way so that its heatmap will look like this:

[image: Matrix heatmap]

This should be an asymmetric variant of the Cuthill-McKee algorithm (or any kind of other algorithm which does the same).

Question: is there any kind of such algorithm in any Python library like numpy, scipy etc.?

Comment: there was such a question, but no ready algorithm for the issue http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22639/reducing-the-bandwidth-of-non-symmetric-matrix

Comment: And by "like this" you mean what exactly?

Comment: @NicoSchertler the rows and columns should be reordered in a such way, that the matrix will seem diagonal (as much as an asymmetric matrix can look diagonal). What I mean is that the I need an algorithm to minimize the total bandwidth of the sparse matrix.